# Measurement of Cmos Parasitic capacitors

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, parasitic-capacitance

i've had a question which asks if we assume that capacitance of capacitors with w/l of 1u/0.5 are 
[image]

then what are capacitance of capacitors (with the actual w/l)

now i know cgs in saturation for example is cgs0+2/3Cox(w)(L) but wouldn't Cgs0 change with new size ? if so how much ? and what about csb ? isnt it zero ? also in other questions i've seen asking capacitance of Cgb or Cgd too what about measuring them ?

The circuit : [image]

Comment: are you using discrete components, or is this for an IC design? In the first case, components have datasheets that list capacitance over voltage ([example](https://www2.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/NTND31225CZ-D-1387707.pdf)), in the second case, this is something that you typically measure using a test wafer containing the cells you plan to use.

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, you're right, the capacitance changes, as a function of the distance between carriers / conductors. But: involving gate, this is something that depends on the geometry of your transistor, so it becomes impossible to calculate manually, typically.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is when we are assuming an IC design but im preparing for exam and this is all that i have : capacitance of capacitors with certain w & L and then their actual capacitance with their real size (W) & (L)

Comment: then that's a "depends on the geometry, can't be generally answered", or it depends on some assumptions that we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Some capacitances are (roughly) proportional to the gate width, some to the gate length, and some to the gate area. The question is asking you to figure out how \$C_{gs}\$ and \$C_{sb}\$ will change as the physical dimensions change.

Basically, the question is asking whether you know what these capacitances really mean and where they exist in the physical device.